# HHClient throw Unbound name error for functions in HSL

Tags: php, hacklang

I am pretty new to hacklang. I have a piece of code (copied from the HSL github page)

```
use namespace HH\Lib\{Vec,Dict,Keyset,Str,Math};


function main(vec<?int> $foo): vec<string> {
  return $foo
    |> Vec\filter_nulls($$)
    |> Vec\map($$, $it ==> (string) $it);
}
```

Filename: abc.hack
My composer.json looks like

```
{
    "require": {
        "hhvm/hhvm-autoload": "^3.1",
        "hhvm/hsl": "^4.41"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "hhvm/hhast": "^4.64",
        "hhvm/hacktest": "^2.2",
        "facebook/fbexpect": "^2.7"
    }
}
```

I have included hsl .  What am I doing wrong here ? I tested with other HSL functions as well , looks like hh_client is not able to detect the HSL functions and
throw *Unbound name (typing): HH\Lib\Vec\filter_nulls* sort of error.

Comment: Did HSL install properly via composer?

Comment: I have put ignored_paths = ["vendor/*"] . can this be a reason ?

Comment: Oh yes, that should be the cause. I'm guessing you were seeing many errors from vendor/ - you can ask a separate question to address those if you wish.

Comment: Yes . Because I saw a bunch of errors. If you can add this as an answer here . I can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, `ignored_paths: ["vendor/*"]` (`ignored_paths` being an hhconfig option [available since 3.23](https://hhvm.com/blog/2017/11/17/hhvm-3-23.html)) was preventing the typechecker from knowing about HSL for the OP. Generally speaking, suppressing errors in `vendor` isn't straightforward, and requires a bit of research to keep the necessary definitions exposed to the typechecker.